# mysql order by, skip non-alphanumerics

Tags: mysql, sql

In doing a mysql `SORT BY` title, I get the following results:

```
#314: Basket Case
$1.2 Billion Scam: Ft. Frauderdale
(Dis)Members Only
- M -
...And Something Makes 3
3:10 to Yuma (2007)
```

How would I ignore the special characters, so the results would be sorted as follows:

```
$1.2 Billion Scam: Ft. Frauderdale
3:10 to Yuma (2007)
#314: Basket Case
...And Something Makes 3
(Dis)Members Only
- M -
```

Comment: Can you list out the **exact** order that the 6 rows should appear in?

Comment: The top entry is what I currently have. The bottom entry is what I need. It is exact... -- 0-9, a-z

Answer (score 0):

Nested replaces to achieve a column without special char, something ugly like

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(field, '.', ''), '#', '') AS fld
FROM table
ORDER BY fld
```

Comment: Wouldn't this get rid of some of the results? Please see updated question.

Comment: You will have to do all the replacing directly in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @PM77-1 is that so? I thought MySQL is not SQL complying by allowing this. +1

Comment: @Joop Eggen - You misunderstood me. MySql will allow such ALIAS use just fine. I meant that your output will not show the result OP wants.